# Problem with array of refs to reference a particular column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I can't get `refs` working. I want to render several columns and then render items that are placed over the right column. For example, declared items: `const items = [0, 2, 5]` should be rendered over the grid like that (assuming that first column has index 0):

[image: this is what I want to achieve]

I want to use `refs` on columns for getting column positions (using getBoundingClientRect() just for the idea) but my `columnsRefs[index].current` is null even though refs are assigned in `componentDidMount` as it's recommended. Here is my code:

```js
import * as React from 'react';

export const GridColumn = (props: {forwardedRef?: any }) => (
    <div style={{borderRight: "1px solid #ababab", width: "20px", height: "200px"}} ref={props.forwardedRef}></div>
);

interface GridProps {
}

export class Grid extends React.Component<GridProps, any> {
    public constructor(props: GridProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            columns: []
        }
    }

    private columnRefs = new Array<React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>>();

    public componentDidMount(){
        // setup the columns with refs
        const columnIds = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
        const columns = columnIds.map(id => {
            const ref = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
            this.columnRefs.push(ref);
            return (<GridColumn forwardedRef={ref}/>)
        });

        this.setState({columns: columns});
    }

    public render() {
        // setup the items
        const items = [
            0, 2, 5
        ]

        let elements = items.map(item => {
            if(this.columnRefs[item] && this.columnRefs[item].current) {
                return (
                    <div style={{backgroundColor: "blue", 
                        opacity: 0.5, 
                        position: "absolute",
                        width: "10px", 
                        height: "20px",
                        left: `${this.columnRefs[item].current.getBoundingClientRect().left}px`,
                        top: "0"}}>
                    </div>);
            }
            else {
                return undefined;
            }
        });

        return (
        <div style={{width: "500px", height: "200px", position: "relative"}}>
            {elements}
            <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
                {this.state.columns}
            </div>
        </div>);
    }
}
```

What do I do wrong so that the condition in `render` `if(this.columnRefs[item] && this.columnRefs[item].current)` is all the time false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not store your rendered components in state. State is for data you want to transform into markup. Here is modified code with annotations:

```js
// Now component properly forwards ref
const GridColumn = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div
    style={{ borderRight: "1px solid #ababab", width: "20px", height: "200px" }}
    ref={ref}
    {...props}
  ></div>
));

class Grid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      columns: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
      rendered: false
    };
  }

  // When you want to use collection of refs, you can set up your own storage for them
  // I use Set because it will prevent duplicates
  // It is important that when component will be removed it's ref will turn into `null`, so you will have to check if your div still exists
  columnRefs = new Set();

  componentDidUpdate() {
    // you will see your refs set in console on each render
    console.debug(this.columnRefs);
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    // You need to rerender to render something from refs
    this.setState({rendered: true});
  }
  
  render() {
    const items = [0, 2, 5];

    let elements = items.map((item) => {
      // turn set into array and filter out null
      let refArray = [...this.columnRefs].filter(Boolean);
      if (refArray[item]) {
        return (
          <div
            key={item}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "blue",
              opacity: 0.5,
              position: "absolute",
              width: "10px",
              height: "20px",
              left: `${refArray[item].getBoundingClientRect().left}px`,
              top: "0",
            }}
          ></div>
        );
      } else {
        return undefined;
      }
    });

    return (
      <div style={{ width: "500px", height: "200px", position: "relative" }}>
        {elements}
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          {/* We use here ref callback to store forwarded ref into out set */}
          {this.state.columns.map((item) => (
            <GridColumn key={item} ref={(ref) => this.columnRefs.add(ref)} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### What to read:

- [callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs)
- [forwarding refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)
- [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

### Example

Reproducible and partially fixed example: https://jsfiddle.net/moL1sbzj/

Comment: Thank you, it works! I think I got fooled by typescript types, as callback refs api is marked as `Legacy`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if refs are needed at all

Use left:

```
left: item * 20 + 'px',
```

it's cheaper than `.current.getBoundingClientRect().left`

result:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/babel">
      const {useEffect, Fragment, useState} = React;  

      const GridColumn = (props) => (
        <div
          style={{ borderRight: "1px solid #ababab", width: "20px", height: "200px" }}
          {...props}
        ></div>
      );

      class Grid extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            columns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
            rendered: false
          };
        }

        componentDidUpdate() {
          // you will see your refs set in console on each render
          // console.debug(this.columnRefs);
        }

        componentDidMount() {
          // You need to rerender to render something from refs
          this.setState({ rendered: true });
        }

        render() {
          const items = [0, 2, 5];
          return (
            <div
              style={{
                width: "500px",
                height: "200px",
                position: "relative"
              }}
            >
              <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                {this.state.columns.map((item, index) => (
                  <GridColumn key={item}>
                    {items.includes(index) && (
                      <div
                        style={{
                          backgroundColor: "blue",
                          opacity: 0.5,
                          width: "10px",
                          height: "20px"
                        }}
                      ></div>
                    )}
                  </GridColumn>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }
      ReactDOM.render(<Grid />, document.getElementById("root"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Multicolumn example**:

`getWidth` function was added for calculate fill (width):

```
    getWidth = (arr, index) => {
      return arr.includes(index + 1) ? 20 : 10;
    };
```

using this:

```
    width: this.getWidth(items, index) + "px",
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/babel">
      const {useEffect, Fragment, useState} = React;  

      const GridColumn = (props) => (
        <div
          style={{ borderRight: "1px solid #ababab", width: "20px", height: "200px" }}
          {...props}
        ></div>
      );

      class Grid extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            columns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
            rendered: false
          };
        }

        componentDidUpdate() {
          // you will see your refs set in console on each render
          // console.debug(this.columnRefs);
        }

        componentDidMount() {
          // You need to rerender to render something from refs
          this.setState({ rendered: true });
        }


        getWidth = (arr, index) => {
          return arr.includes(index + 1) ? 20 : 10;
        };

        render() {
          const items = [0,1, 2, 5];
          return (
            <div
              style={{
                width: "500px",
                height: "200px",
                position: "relative"
              }}
            >
              <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                {this.state.columns.map((item, index) => (
                  <GridColumn key={item}>
                    {items.includes(index) && (
                      <div
                        style={{
                          backgroundColor: "blue",
                          opacity: 0.5,
                          width: this.getWidth(items, index) + "px",
                          height: "20px"
                        }}
                      ></div>
                    )}
                  </GridColumn>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }
      ReactDOM.render(<Grid />, document.getElementById("root"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

for achieve this effect (no vertical lines) use style:

```
.afterFull::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
  height: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-color: var(--color);
}
```

in code:

```
<div
  className="afterFull"
  style={{
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    opacity: 0.5,
    width: this.getWidth(items, index) + 0 + "px",
    height: "20px",
    "--color": "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)"
  }}
/>
```

Comment: That's how I got the screenshot in the question :D Yeah I agree this is enough for example above but I'm thinking on using it in more complex way where I'd need to access more properties of columns.

Comment: @Jacek It almost does not depend on what you need, in my practice I hardly use refs. Some  find them unsafe. I would show how this could be achieved, but so far it reminded me of a calendar or piano keys.

Comment: @Jacek I added a snippet to show how to do the same without refs

Comment: This is also nice, however... I sometimes need blue rectangles to be rendered across multiple columns, that's why I would like to handle them in the outer container

Comment: @Jacek this can be done without any problems, no refs are needed for this, you need to work with datа, not DOM elements

Comment: How do you define a multiple columns item [1,2,3] or else? I added other snippet